# Does BigQuery `ANY_VALUE` give me any guarantees of values being from the same row?

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider the following query:

```sql
with abc as (
  select 1 as a, 1 as b, 2 as c  
  union all select 1, 3, 4  
  union all select 1, 5, 6  
  union all select 2, 7, 8  
  union all select 2, 9, 10
)

select
  a,
  any_value(b),
  any_value(c)
from abc
group by a
```

Are there any guarantees as to whether the `b` and `c` values picked by `ANY_VALUE` will be from the same row? In other words, can I be sure that *if* the values picked for `b` are `1` and `9` (yes, I know there are no guarantees that this will be the case, or that it will be the same each time) then `c` is `2` and `10`, respectively?

Answer (score 7):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> ANY_VALUE returns expression for some row in the group. It is **nondeterministic** which row to choose

To make sure that b and c is taken from the same row - use below approach

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM abc t
GROUP BY a
```

to also make sure those values not just from the same row but always from the same rows from run to run - use below approach

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY b,c LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM abc t
GROUP BY a
```

Comment: Your answers always blow my mind with new SQL stuff I did not even imagine existed. The `SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t) FROM abc t GROUP BY a` is just brilliant.

Comment: @neydroydrec - glad it helps this way! :o) in my answers I always try to come up with non-trivial solution. btw, consider voting up answer :o)